# Regular expression in python re.findall()

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I tryed the folowing:

I want to split with the re.findall()

```
str="<abc>somechars<*><def>somechars<*><ghj>somechars<*><ijk>somechars<*>"
print(re.findall('<(abc|ghj)>.*?<*>',str))
```

The out should be

```
['<abc>somechars<*>','<ghj>somechars<*>']
```

In notepad, if I try this expression I get right, but here:

```
['abc', 'ghj']
```

Any idea?
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: If those are literal `*` that you're looking for, you should probably escape them

Comment: Its funny how this `<*>` accdidently works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(<(?:abc|ghj)>.*?<\*>)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/12

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(<(?:abc|ghj)>.*?<\*>)', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"<abc>somechars<*><def>somechars<*><ghj>somechars<*><ijk>somechars<*>"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're capturing `(abc|ghj)`. Use a non-capturing group `(?:abc|ghj)` instead.

Also, you should escape the second `*` in your regex since you want a literal asterisk: `<\*>` rather than `<*>`.

```
>>> s = '<abc>somechars<*><def>somechars<*><ghj>somechars<*><ijk>somechars<*>'
>>> re.findall(r'<(?:abc|ghj)>.*?<\*>', s)
['<abc>somechars<*>', '<ghj>somechars<*>']
```

Also also, avoid shadowing the built-in name `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the group a non-capturing group:

```
str="<abc>somechars<*><def>somechars<*><ghj>somechars<*><ijk>somechars<*>"
print(re.findall('<(?:abc|ghj)>.*?<*>',str))
```

The function returns the groups from left to right, and since you specified a group it left out the entire match.

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html#re.findall)

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match

.